# Scanning folder for files instead of array

Tags: php, file, filesystems

I have this code:

```
<?php
$allowed = array('file1', 'file2', 'file3');

if (in_array($_GET["url"], $allowed)) {
    // You can include
} else {
   // Error message and dont include
}
?>
```

But instead of writing all the filenames in the array, how can i do so that the files in for example my folder FILES/ is accepted an no other files. How to do that?

Comment: @ajreal, that's not completely true; what Moussa is doing it the *only* way to do it safely, by whitelisting the the files that may be included.  That said, it's still pretty horrible.

Comment: ops, posting wrongly, I referring to the rest of the answer

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`file_exists`](http://php.net/file_exists) function like this:

```
if (file_exists('FILES/'.basename($_GET["url"]))) {
    // You can include
} else {
   // Error message and dont include
}
```

Comment: Careful with relative paths in `$_GET['url']`!

Comment: from the file_exists docs, "Checks whether a file or directory exists".  So, this will allow the app to try to include directories, which will cause errors.  I've also fixed the relative path problem in my answer below.

Comment: you will still include directories.

Answer (score 0):

Function to retrieve files in a folder:

```
<?
function fGetFilesInFolder($sFolder) {

    $aFiles = array();
    if(file_exists($sFolder)) {
        if ($handle = opendir($sFolder)) {
            while (false !== ($sFile = readdir($handle))) {
                if ($sFile != "." && $sFile != "..") $aFiles[] = $sFile;
            }
            closedir($handle);
        }
    }
    return $aFiles;
}
?>
```